# How to extract Vista file tags?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-vista

Vista introduced tags for the files. But how to extract these tags, let's say in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Channel9 thread](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/422940-Reading-file-tags-from-code-in-Windows-Vista/) that has some answers.